# Drop down menu- how to reverse animation on second click of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a drop down menu using jQuery.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="overlaydiv">This is my menu!</div>  

    <div class="row one">
      <div class="large-12 columns">



      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row two">
      <div class="large-12 columns">

         <button id="b1">Drop down the menu!</button>   

      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS for overlay:

```
.overlaydiv { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; background-color: aquamarine; position: absolute; top: -100%; z-index: 1; }
```

This is jQuery that drops down the menu on click:

```
$("#b1").on("click", function() {

         $(".overlaydiv").animate({top: "0%"}, 200, 'swing');

      });
```

What would be the easiest way to reverse animation on second click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I can think of is using CSS transition.

So, here's the CSS:

```
.overlaydiv{ 
    height: 100vh; 
    width: 100vw; 
    background-color: aquamarine; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: -100%; 
    z-index: 1; 
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.overlaydiv.active{
    top: 0%;
}
```

And the JS

```
$("#b1, .overlaydiv").on("click", function() {

     $(".overlaydiv").toggleClass("active");

});
```

Comment: @user7393973 I haven't (already packed my things) but from the question I assume the original code by OP is working so I just extrapolate from there

Comment: @user7393973 I have edited. should be working now. here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fw3d3fah/

Answer (score 0):

You can check that to assign `class` **active** on your button and make action on it.

```js
$("#b1").on("click", function() {
  if($(this).hasClass("active")){
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(".overlaydiv").animate({top: "-100%"}, 200, 'swing');
  }else{
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".overlaydiv").animate({top: "0%"}, 200, 'swing');
  }
});
```

```css
.overlaydiv { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; background-color: aquamarine; position: absolute; top: -100%; z-index: 1; }

#b1  {position:relative;z-index:2}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlaydiv">This is my menu!</div>  

    <div class="row one">
      <div class="large-12 columns">



      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row two">
      <div class="large-12 columns">

         <button id="b1">Drop down the menu!</button>   

      </div>
    </div>
```